# Twitter api statuses/update throws an error of authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am building a bot on twitter with javascript to send a post from my own twitter account. But I am getting the following error:

```
{
  code: 220,
  message: 'Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.'
}
```

I am not using OAuth since I will be the only user of this bot, I just want to send a twitter post inside a certain listener that watches for some event. Here is the inside of my function to send a post on twitter:

```
const Twitter = require('twitter')

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  bearer_token: process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
})

async function sendTwitterPost() {
  try {
    const response = await client.post('statuses/update', { 
      status: 'Event occured!',
    })
    console.log(response)
    console.log("Success")
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    console.log("ERROR WHILE SENDING TWITTER POST!")
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the v1.1 API (elevated - essential access only provided access to v2)? Does your app have read and write access? Have you configured your access token and secret correctly?

Comment: @AndyPiper I have elevated access, I have deleted and created access token and secret multiple times to make sure it is correct. My app have read and write access. But now I see under my access token it says "Created with Read Only permissions" for my twitter account. I couldn't find anywhere to add a write permission on that token or recreate the token with write permission.

Comment: You'll need to change the permissions under User Authentication settings (under the OAuth 1.0A settings) in the developer dashboard. Once that is set, you can regenerate the token with r/w permissions.